# New line feed in json data

Tags: json, hive, newline

I'm having a json file as :-

```
{
    VALUES: [
        {
            "UTAGID": "SYSTEM_CHILLER1",
            "tagName": "P1",
            "tagValue": "10",
            "tagTime": "2015-07-23T14:29:30.731Z",
            "tagQuality": "128"
        },
        {
            "UTAGID": "SYSTEM_CHILLER1",
            "tagName": "P1",
            "tagValue": "10",
            "tagTime": "2015-07-23T14:29:30.731Z",
            "tagQuality": "128"
        },
        {
            "UTAGID": "SYSTEM_CHILLER1",
            "tagName": "P1",
            "tagValue": "10",
            "tagTime": "2015-07-23T14:29:30.731Z",
            "tagQuality": "128"
        }
    ]
};
```

where each record is not on a single line.I'm able to retrieve values from a hive table based on this if each record appears on a single line else it shows null values.
What could be the reason?how do I insert new line feed after each record?
Thanks

Comment: What you done as code?

Comment: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TB1(UTAGID String,tagName String,tagValue String,tagTime String,tagQuality String) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("UTAGID"="$.UTAGID","tagName"="$.tagName","tagValue"="$.tagValue","tagTime"="$.tagTime","tagQuality"="$.tagQuality")

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/tmp/trial.json' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE TB1...but this query works only if each record is on a new line